# Kalman Filter: Why $ Q $ Discrete Is Defined as $\int_0^Te^{\mathbf{A}\tau} Q e^{\mathbf{A}^T \tau} d\tau$?

Tags: kalman-filters, discretization

I would like to ask, why in the transformation to the discretization, $\mathbf{Q}$ is obtained from the expression containing the integral (image attached), what is the theory behind it?

Comment: Could you please mark my answer? Or address what is missing? Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere prior to this step (in the State Transition Equations) there was something along the lines of
$$
\mathbf{e ^{A(t-\tau)}}
$$
which probably factors as

$$
\mathbf{e ^{A(t-\tau)}}=\mathbf{e ^{A(t)}} \mathbf{e ^{-A(\tau)}}$$

so things like
$$
\int_0^T \mathbf{e ^{A(t-\tau)}} \mathbf{G}\mathbf{d\tau}$$
which should have a certain familiar form, can under certain conditions as
$$
 \mathbf{e ^{A(t)}}\int_0^T  \mathbf{e ^{A(-\tau)}}\mathbf{G}\mathbf{d\tau}
$$
There is also a commutative property on $\mathbf{e ^{A(-\tau)}}$ that is important.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you discretize Differntial Equation.
Actually a linear differential equation.

The question is why the Matrix Exponential?
Well, try to remember what are the solutions of [Linear Scalar Differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation).
The solutions are formed by the expontial function.
Hence what you see is the Exponent of a Matrix (Since in the General Kalman case we have a vector Linear Differential Equation) as solution (Which is the integration) and we discretize this because in real life the model is discrete.

You may have a look at [ECE 595 - Discrete-Time Control Systems - Discretization of Continuous Time State Space Systems](http://www.engr.iupui.edu/~skoskie/ECE595_f05/handouts/discretization.pdf).
The solution given there for the Differential Equation in a vector form holds for the cases all variables and coefficients are scalars.

Comment: Thanks Royi. Really useful ECE 595 link.  I'm gonna find that other thread where the person asks the question directly and link to it there.

Comment: plus oned the "your welcome" comment by accident but don't know how to undo it. Also, put a 1 on the answer.